# How to handle namespaced duplicate xml tags with Jackson

Tags: java, xml, annotations, jackson

Is it possible using Jackson, to handle duplicate xml tags based off of their namespace?

The code below throws a JsonMappingException : Multiple fields representing property "url"

```
private final ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();

private static final String xml =
        "<example xmlns:test='http://test.com/'>" +
            "<test:url>www.namespace.com'</test:url>" +
            "<url>www.url.com'</url>" +
        "</example>";

@Test
public void parseXml() throws Exception {
    Example example = xmlMapper.readValue(xml, Example.class);

    assert example.namespaceUrl.equals("www.namespace.com");
}

public static class Example {

    @JsonProperty("url")
    public String namespaceUrl;

    @JsonProperty("url")
    public String url;

}
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You could easily handle this use case with a JAXB (JSR-222) implementation:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: how? I have javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED in my package-info. Jackson is still blowing up because it sees two elements with the same name. The funny thing is, the element names won't even end up on the json payload, so it really doesn't even matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that currently -- you can not use properties that only differ by namespace. This is not a fundamental limitation; that is, with more work, it could be supported; but it is current limitation.